# VS Code. error workspacefolder can to be resolved

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When running c++ code in vs code, it gives an error "workspaceFolder can not be resolved".
But in visual studio everything works fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I created plugin which recreates utilization of VSCode predefined variables:

It also very useful in TDD with C++, IMHO.

This plugins runs on c/cpp file type any command line you provide, with predefined variables any time you save that file.

Did that helped you to run your shell code with VSCode ${workspaceFolder} ?

Cheer!

```js
        const filePath = document.fileName;
        const fileWorkspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(vscode.Uri.file(filePath));
        const cmd = this._testCommands.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(document.languageId)); // Get the files and command values
        let commandText = cmd[document.languageId];
        try {
            if (fileWorkspaceFolder) {
                if (commandText.includes('${workspaceFolder}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${workspaceFolder}', workspaceFolderUri?.uri.fsPath ?? '');
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${workspaceFolderBasename}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${workspaceFolderBasename}', workspaceFolderUri?.name ?? '');
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${file}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${file}', document.uri.fsPath);
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${fileWorkspaceFolder}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${fileWorkspaceFolder}', fileWorkspaceFolder?.uri.fsPath ?? '');
                }
                if (commandText.includes('${relativeFileDirname}')) {
                    commandText = commandText.replace('${relativeFileDirname}', path.relative(fileWorkspaceFolder?.uri.fsPath ?? '', path.dirname(filePath)));
                }
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileBasename}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileBasename}', vscode.workspace.asRelativePath(filePath));
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileBasenameNoExtension}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileBasenameNoExtension}', path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath)));
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileExtname}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileExtname}', filePath.split('.').pop());
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileDirname}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileDirname}', path.dirname(filePath));
            }
            if (commandText.includes('${fileDirnameBasename}')) {
                commandText = commandText.replace('${fileDirnameBasename}', path.basename(path.dirname(filePath)));
            }
            const regex = /\${env:(.*?)}/g;
            const matches = commandText.match(regex);
            if (matches) {
                const resolvedString = matches.reduce((acc: string, match: string) => {
                    const variableName = match.slice(6, -1);
                    const variableValue = process.env[variableName] ?? '';
                    return acc.replace(match, variableValue);
                }, commandText);
                commandText = resolvedString;
            }
```